# How do you know which string to provide as a selector for Swift functions?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

Sometimes when I am working with selectors in Swift (i.e. the `Selector` type), the string literal that I provide for the `action` parameter to methods like `targetForAction(_:withSender:)` or `addTarget(_:action:)` doesn't invoke or map to the actual Swift function to which I am expecting.

For example, when an instance of `MyResponder` as shown below is in the responder chain, it cannot be found when calling `targetForAction(_:withSender)` using the string `showImage:`.  What is the pattern for knowing what is the proper string literal to provide for different types of Swift function signatures and the options for required and/or omitted argument labels?

```
import UIKit

class MyResponder: UIResponder {

    func showImage( named filename: String ) {
        print( "Loading image..." )
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonTapped( sender: AnyObject? ) {
        if let responder = self.targetForAction( "showImage:", withSender: self ) as? MyResponder {
            responder.showImage(named: "my_image" )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?

Comment: Here's my guess: Because it's totally incomprehensible? What do these _strings_ have to do with the responder chain anyway? What's the point of the question? Where's your actual _code_? What are you trying to do? Use the responder chain _how_?

Comment: String literals are the way that you specifiy a `Selector` in Swift, and selectors are how you use `targetForAction:withSender:` when using the responder chain.  I added a gist a minute ago for more context: https://gist.github.com/patricklynch/0ab26319bd46afd33886.

Comment: I know how to use `targetForAction`. What I don't know is how _you_ want to use it. And I'm not going to read some gist to find out. If you have a question, ask it here, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some trial, error and encouragement from commenters, I managed to figure out the pattern!

The string literal has to follow Objective-C syntax translated from the signature of your Swift function, which is an interesting tidbit that wasn't obvious at first, but makes perfect sense when you consider the purpose things like the `@objc` attribute.  In writing up a better code sample, I seem to have figured out the pattern for the mappings myself.

`functionName` + (`With` + `First`) +  `:`  + (`second`) +  `:`     etc.

Where what's in the parenthesis is required only when the argument label is required (i.e. not omitted).  And remember to capitalize `With` and `First`.

In each of the following examples, `myObject` will return itself as the target for the provided selector, indicating that the string literal provided as the `Selector` did in fact map that the Swift function for which it was intended.

```
import UIKit

class MyObject : UIResponder {
    func someFunction() {}
    func someFunction(param:String) {}
    func someLabeledFunction(param param:String) {}
    func someTwoArgumentFunction(param1:String, param2:String) {}
    func someTwoArgumentNoLabelFunction(param1:String, _ param2:String) {}
    func someHalfLabeledTwoArgumentFunction(param1 param1:String, _ param2:String) {}
    func someCompletelyLabeledTwoArgumentFunction(param1 param1:String, param2:String) {}
}

let myObject = MyObject()
myObject.targetForAction("someFunction", withSender: nil)
myObject.targetForAction("someFunction:", withSender: nil)
myObject.targetForAction("someLabeledFunctionWithParam:", withSender: nil)
myObject.targetForAction("someTwoArgumentFunction:param2:", withSender: nil)
myObject.targetForAction("someTwoArgumentNoLabelFunction::", withSender: nil)
myObject.targetForAction("someHalfLabeledTwoArgumentFunctionWithParam1::", withSender: nil)
myObject.targetForAction("someCompletelyLabeledTwoArgumentFunctionWithParam1:param2:", withSender: nil)
```

Comment: Well, I don't see how this is different from what I say in my book: `http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors`. Also, I don't see how it answers the question, since your `showSpace:` was correct. And your labeled first parameters are completely artificial, since the whole idea is that you don't do that, since it doesn't correspond to Objective-C.